# sharepoint forms library

Tags: document

I'm trying to find a template document, but it is not displaying in SP2013.

Under the Document Library --> Advanced Settings --> I can click on the Edit URL, and the template appears. The templateURL is myApp/Forms/template.dotm

However, when I go to the sharepoint site https://.../MyApp/Forms, nothing is in the list. However, if I go back to Library > Open With Explorer, all the forms (including my template) are there.

Any insights into what is going on would be great!

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint is simply hiding the view files and the template file for you in usual GUI mode, as there is no reason for them to be visible in a document library. In Explorer View however, everything is visible, including the Forms folder, view files and template file.

Comment: Seems reasonable. However, how can I add permissions to the template document? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered this was not needed. The problem was I was using a like directly to the template to create new documents for the Document Library, as I was needing the template macro enabled.

It appeared that my macros were not starting correctly. Further examination showed the macros were correctly enabled after all, just not properly picked up by the AutoNew inbuild macro. I have removed direct access to the template now, and just refer to the standard New Document Coreinvoke routine instead.